# What's the protocol when you've improved a jQuery plugin from GitHub?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, github

I've been using a plugin that dwells on GitHub. I've made a number of what-seem-to-me-to-be improvements. What's the right way to let the author/community have a look? I'm not after any glory :)

Comment: Can you not just email the developer and ask them?  Different devs would probably prefer different things :)

Comment: @Archer  Yeah, good call. I just did. I'll delete this question soon unless some weighty answers roll in :)

Comment: This would probably be better on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to simply send the author a 'pull request'. That is one of the main features of Github, that makes it really cool. Fork his repository and commit your changes to your fork and then send him a 'pull request' giving details of your changes.

A pull request will list the commits you have made and also show diffs to files, so it makes it very easy for the author to go through the changes you have made and understand what's the intention.

He or you can also comment and discuss further on the same if things aren't perfect.

Comment: Ah! This is the kind of insider knowledge I was after :) Thanks.